# Saca variable de un array en PHP con CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hola tengo los siguiente en CodeIgniter:

MODELO:

```
public function GetHoraPaciente($rut_paciente,$estado){ // muestra todas las horas pedidas del paciente

    $this->db->where("rut_paciente",$rut_paciente);
    $this->db->where("estado",$estado);

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->select('rut_medico');
    $this->db->select('fecha_programada');
    $this->db->select('hora_programada');
    $this->db->from("horas_medicas");
    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

public function GetDocdate($rut_medico){ // muestra datos del doctor segun su rut;

    $this->db->where("rut",$rut_medico);
    $this->db->select('nombre');
    $this->db->select('apellido');
    $this->db->from("medico");
    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function HoraPaciente(){  //muestra las horas del paciente

    $rut_paciente = $this->input->post('rut_paciente');
    $estado = $this->input->post('estado');
    $this->load->model('ChincolModel');
    $data = $this->ChincolModel->GetHoraPaciente($rut_paciente,$estado);

    if (!$data == null) {

        // saco los datos la variable data
        $id = $data['id'];
        $rut_medico = $data['rut_medico'];
        $fecha_programada = $data['fecha_programada'];
        $hora_programada = $data['hora_programada'];

        //pido nombre y y apellido al module GetDocdate con el rut que saque de $data
        $this->load->model('ChincolModel');
        $medico = $this->ChincolModel->GetDocdate($rut_medico);
        // saco los datos de la variable $medico
        $nombre = $medico['nombre'];
        $apellido = $medico['apellido'];

        // los almaceno en un array  y los muestro en JSON
        $data5 = array("rut_medico" => "$rut_medico", "id" => "$id", "fecha_programada" => "$fecha_programada",
        "hora_programada" => "$hora_programada","nombre_medico" => "$nombre","apellido_medico" => "$apellido");

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data5);
            
    }

}
```

Por alguna razón que desconozco, no me esta llenando las variables que saco de `$data`, estas quedan `null` y me imposibilita seguir con el objetivo...

Que puede ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablemente ocurrirá si te trae datos porque la función del modelo parece que está correcta. Deberías comprobar el resultado de la consulta:

```
$data = $this->ChincolModel->GetHoraPaciente($rut_paciente,$estado);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data);die();
if (!$data == null) {
```

Si te imprime algo diferente a `null` significa que la consulta es correcta. Supuestamente el error está en la validación del `if`.

Cambia `if (!$data == null) {` por alguna línea de estas:

- `if(!is_null($data)){  }`
- `if ($data != null)`
- `if($data)`

La forma que estas obteniendo los datos de la variable `$data` es incorrecta ya que estas usandolo como si fuera un array y desde el modelo lo obtienes como objeto, si quieres obtenerlo como array debes modificar el modelo de la siguiente manera:

- return $query->result_array();

y en el controlador, de está manera:

- $id = $data[0]['id'];

Si solo es un registro puedes usar en el modelo lo siguiente:

- return $query->row_array();

para de esta manera tener el controlador como lo tenias:

- $id = $data["id"];

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar comprobar el resultado desde el mismo query

Ejecutas:

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

al final y verificas que este bien formado.

Luego revisar si retorna el valor en el controlador con un

```
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Saca por un var_dump los valores que tiene el array $data tras la consulta, podría ser que tenga datos pero no los que tu esperas. Prueba con eso y me cuentas.

Comment: me podrías dar un ejemplo de como sacar los datos con var_dump por favor :o

Answer (score 0):

Accede a las variables como objeto  $data->id,$data->rut_medico ,etc
la función row devuelve un objeto y lo estas accediendo como array.

Fuente: [funcion row](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows)

Comment: Probe con esta forma y aún así me retorna null, los datos si están llegando porque al mandar en json el $data los el array con los datos...